# Почему не работает morphology для одного слова?

Tags: sphinx

Использую manticore - форк sphinx.
Для RT индекса установил опцию

```
morphology = lemmatize_ru
```

В общем морфология работает, но для одного слова, а именно слова "красный", не работает.
Возможно есть и другие слова для которых не работает, но пока не нашел.
В чем может быть причина?

Comment: `CALL KEYWORDS('красный', 'ваш-индекс');` что выдает?

Answer (score 0):

"красный" - это основная лемма. Прилагательное мужского рода.
Его просто некуда уже лемматизировать.

Вообще, если сразу после запроса смотреть вывод show meta, то там будет видно, какие именно слова участвовали в поиске.

Answer (score 0):

Для красн* есть несколько лемм: "красное", "красный", "красная". Например:

```
mysql> call keywords('красному', 'idx_min');
+------+------------------+----------------+
| qpos | tokenized        | normalized     |
+------+------------------+----------------+
| 1    | красному         | красное        |
+------+------------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> call keywords('красной', 'idx_min');
+------+----------------+----------------+
| qpos | tokenized      | normalized     |
+------+----------------+----------------+
| 1    | красной        | красная        |
+------+----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> call keywords('красный', 'idx_min');
+------+----------------+----------------+
| qpos | tokenized      | normalized     |
+------+----------------+----------------+
| 1    | красный        | красный        |
+------+----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Это в некоторых случаях позволяет немного улучшить качество поиска. В некоторых, конечно, и ухудшает.

Если вам нужна более общая форма, то возможно вам подойдет morphology = stem_ru, а не lemmatize_ru. В этом случае все будет сведено до "красн":

```
mysql> call keywords('красный', 'idx_min2');
+------+----------------+------------+
| qpos | tokenized      | normalized |
+------+----------------+------------+
| 1    | красный        | красн      |
+------+----------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> call keywords('красного', 'idx_min2');
+------+------------------+------------+
| qpos | tokenized        | normalized |
+------+------------------+------------+
| 1    | красного         | красн      |
+------+------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> call keywords('красных', 'idx_min2');
+------+----------------+------------+
| qpos | tokenized      | normalized |
+------+----------------+------------+
| 1    | красных        | красн      |
+------+----------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```